# How do you animate a prefab using an animator controller?

Tags: unity, animation

How do you animate a prefab using an animator controller? I had an enemy, that had functioning animations when it was not a prefab, but when I made it into one, it stopped working. Do I need to change the avatar, or controller, or something else? I'm not sure. Thank you

Comment: How did you set it up? A prefab with animation should work exactly the same way as a non prefab

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete steps to make a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of the problem.